# Elastic Search delete a single element inside a field on _source

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

i`m trying to delete a element inside a field of my elastic field, current, I have this struct of data:

I need in my NODE application to delete a **single** element from **produto_tags** getting the **id_produto_cor**,
for example:

```
  {
        "_index" : "relatorio_recebimento_produto_hml",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "54XZ9HAB4DHa2O1nQlpk",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id_usuario" : 1408,
          "data_criacao" : "2020-03-19T22:10:40.465Z",
          "produto_tags" : [
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "2489664268",
              "tags" : [ ]
            },
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "1000045010",
              "tags" : [ ]
            },
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "1004600287",
              "tags" : [ ]
            },
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "1032013410",
              "tags" : [ ]
            },
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "2468436987",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }
          ],
          "referencia_tags" : [ ],
          "nome_relatorio" : "teste"
        }
      }
```

```
XDELETE
{
  query: {
   match: {
    produto_tags.id_produto_cor: 489664268
   }
  }
}
```

I would expect my data to be like:

```
       "_index" : "relatorio_recebimento_produto_hml",
       "_type" : "_doc",
       "_id" : "xYVD5XAB4DHa2O1ndFo1",
       "_score" : 1.0,
       "_source" : {
         "id_usuario" : 1376,
         "data_criacao" : "2020-03-16T21:32:46.369Z",
         "produto_tags" : [
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "1000045010",
              "tags" : [ ]
            },
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "1004600287",
              "tags" : [ ]
            },
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "1032013410",
              "tags" : [ ]
            },
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "2468436987",
              "tags" : [ ]
            }
          ],
         "referencia_tags" : { },
         "nome_relatorio" : "teste"
       }
     },
...
```

This is my final structure
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: can you not update the document without the value which you need to remove?

Comment: Could you add the actual result as well as the expected result ?

Comment: I probably could update the entire field of this document, for example:
produto_tags: [1,2,3] and i change to [2,3], but i`d like to remove only one element not the entire field

Answer (score 0):

You can use [_update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

```
POST /index102/_update_by_query
{
  "script":{
    "source":"ctx._source.produto_tags.remove('1029831004')"
  },
  "query":{
    "match_all":{} --> modify query to target specific documents
                   --> match_all will execute script on all documents
  }
}
```

Query for changed structure:
iterate through produto_tags, match with specific value and store the matched object in an array (list). Then iteratate through list and remove the object from produto_tags

```
POST /<index_name>/_update_by_query
{
  "script":{
    "source":"if(ctx._source.produto_tags.size()==0) {return;} def list=[]; for(product in ctx._source.produto_tags) { if (product['id_produto_cor'] ==params.product_id){list.add(product)}} if(list.size()==0) return; for(d in list){ctx._source.produto_tags.remove(ctx._source.produto_tags.indexOf(d))}",
    "params" : {
            "product_id" : "2468436987"
        }

  },
  "query":{
    "match_all":{} --> to select specific documents
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my structure changed, as you can see,

```"produto_tags" : [
            {
              "id_produto_cor" : "2489664268",
              "tags" : [ ]
            },```
i tried to do something like:

  ```"script":{
    "source":"ctx._source.produto_tags.id_produto_cor.remove('2489664268')"
  },```



but my response was: 


 ```"script_stack": [
          "ctx._source.produto_tags.id_produto_cor.remove('2489664268')",
          "                        ^---- HERE"
        ], ```

Comment: @GabrielValensuela  I have updated the answer for new structure